# wp_script_is('enqueued') true, but file not requested in HTML

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

This is really confounding.

In a child theme `functions.php` file, I have confirmed that WP *thinks* my script(s) are enqueued:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_scripts_styles");
function my_scripts_styles() {
wp_register_script('my_gallery',
    get_theme_file_uri('/scripts/main.js'),
    array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'),
    '1.0',
    true
);
wp_enqueue_script('my_gallery');


if ( !wp_script_is('my_gallery', 'enqueued') ) {
    echo '<p>my_gallery failed to queue up!</p>';
} else {
    echo "my_gallery is enqueued.";
}
}
```

Output: `my_gallery is enqueued.`

Based on [this useful bit of debug code](https://wpengineer.com/2308/debug-enqueued-scripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/):

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fb_urls_of_enqueued_stuff');
function fb_urls_of_enqueued_stuff( $handles = array() ) {
    global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;

    // scripts
    foreach ( $wp_scripts -> registered as $registered )
        $script_urls[ $registered -> handle ] = $registered -> src;
    // styles
    if ( empty( $handles ) ) {
        $handles = array_merge( $wp_scripts -> queue, $wp_styles -> queue );
        array_values( $handles );
    }
    // output of values
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $handles as $handle ) {
        if ( ! empty( $script_urls[ $handle ] ) )
            $output .= $handle . ": " . $script_urls[ $handle ] . '<br />';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

Returns a short list, including correct paths to the above two files:

```
my_gallery: https://example.local/wp-content/themes/my-2020-child/scripts/main.js
twentytwenty-js: https://example.local/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/assets/js/index.js
wp-block-library: /wp-includes/js/dist/block-library.min.js
```

However, those files are neither requested in the HTML nor loaded by the browser. This is confirmed locally in WP Local *and* on a public server.

I can hard-code the load into the theme footer:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php echo '<script src="' . get_theme_file_uri('/scripts/main.js') . '"></script>'?>
```

Then the files show up in the Network tab, and my `console.log('hello')` shows up.

I'm at a loss here. Why is these supposedly enqueued script not getting enqueued?

### Update

Actually it seems to be because one script (actually loading two) depends on the other that the issue is happening.

```
    wp_register_script('my_flickity',
        get_theme_file_uri('/scripts/flickity.min.js'),
        array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('my_flickity');
    if ( !wp_script_is('my_flickity', 'enqueued') ) {
        die("not enqueued."); # Does not die
    }
    if ( !wp_script_is('my_flickity', 'registered') ) {
        die("not registered."); # Does not die
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_gallery',
        get_theme_file_uri('/scripts/main.js'),
        array( 'my_flickity') # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    );
```

If I remove the `'my_flickity'` dependency, the scripts both load. Do I need to hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` a second time?

#### Update Two

Within the `wp_enqueue_scripts`-hooked script:

```
    if ( !wp_script_is('my_flickity', 'done') ) {
        die("not done."); I DIE!!!
    }
```

Comment: On what action hook are you using `wp_register_script`? I'd guess you're firing it too early.

Comment: add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_scripts_styles");

Comment: actually, I'm enqueueing two scripts, one dependent on the other and this is where the issue is coming up. Updating post now.

Comment: WordPress does not register a script with the handle `jquery-ui` by default. Are you/is one of your extensions registering a script with the `jquery-ui` handle?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't even need to. That solved it. Feel like posting an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not register a script with the handle `jquery-ui` by default, and it will skip printing the markup for any enqueued script for which it is unable to resolve all dependencies at the time of printing. So unless you or another extension is registering or enqueuing a script with the `jquery-ui` handle, your script which depends upon it will not print.

If your script does depend on `jquery-ui`, the following is a list of jQuery UI component handles which are registered by default:

- `jquery-ui-core` (also includes `jquery-ui-widget` and `jquery-ui-position`)
- `jquery-ui-accordion`
- `jquery-ui-autocomplete`
- `jquery-ui-button`
- `jquery-ui-datepicker`
- `jquery-ui-dialog`
- `jquery-ui-menu`
- `jquery-ui-mouse`
- `jquery-ui-progressbar`
- `jquery-ui-selectmenu`
- `jquery-ui-slider`
- `jquery-ui-spinner`
- `jquery-ui-tabs`
- `jquery-ui-tooltip`
- `jquery-ui-checkboxradio`
- `jquery-ui-controlgroup`
- `jquery-ui-draggable`
- `jquery-ui-droppable`
- `jquery-ui-resizable`
- `jquery-ui-selectable`
- `jquery-ui-sortable`
- `jquery-ui-position`
- `jquery-ui-widget`

A nicely formatted list of all of the scripts which WordPress registers by default can be found on [the `wp_enqueue_scripts()` documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress). Alternately, they can also be found in [the source](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L660-L1427) of [the `wp_default_scripts()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_default_scripts/).